# Attachmate Extra : VBA : Print current page

Tags: vba, attachmate-extra

Is there a function that exists to print the current page using Extra and VBA?

I didn't found anything on the internet.. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How is a terminal emulation for mainframes like AS/400 (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/extra/info) connected to printing a page in VBA (Visual Basic for Applications, scripting language used in Microsoft Office products such as Excel)? **EDIT:** Oh I get it, there is a software called "Attachmate Extra"... I'm going to propose an edit to your question then.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes sorry, It is a mainframe that uses VBA also. And it works nearly the same as VBA for Excel... But the problem is that I can't find anything about printing the page.

Comment: OK now it appears I myself was confused and on the wrong track. Appears my edit went through anyway, but it was unnecessary then. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be done easily using the `Session` object and its method `PrintDisplay`

It'll send the current data present on the page to the printer as if you pushed yourself on the printer icon.

`Sess0.PrintDisplay`